# How to Install gtk2-engines-murrine locally?

Tags: linux, terminal, rhel, gtk2, xfce

I tried installing some xfce4 themes locally onto my office machine but whenever I open any gvim files, it throws the following error

```
Gtk-WARNING **: : Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

To resolve this everyone is asking to install using sudo access but I don't have the permission. Does anyone knows how to install it locally ?

Please advice. Thanks!

Update:

1. I tried downloading the packages from following link.
2. https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el6/x86_64/gtk-murrine-engine-0.53.1-1.el6.rf.x86_64.html
3. Unpacked the files using: `rpm2cpio to-install.rpm | cpio -idv`
4. Tried adding the following .so path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

But still faced the same error. Is there anything that needs to be done ?

Comment: A warning is information. Sometimes a warning is meant for developers only. If everything is functioning as expected, and the word *error* doesn't appear, a warning can be ignored.

Comment: @KnudLarsen But every time when I open a gvim it shows up this error and its really horrible to look at. Also seems like its searching for that pkg and it takes like 8 seconds to open a file as compared against normal operation of 2-3sec to open a single gvim file.